# openni_launch works only the first time

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04 with a Kinect. I have noted that openni_launch works only the first time. When it works, on the terminal I have:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch  
[...]   
[ INFO] [1342603480.398058817]: Initializing nodelet with 6 worker threads.  
[ERROR] [1342603484.926529464]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]  
[ERROR] [1342603484.943879879]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]  
[ INFO] [1342603487.444944913]: Number devices connected: 1  
[ INFO] [1342603487.445153962]: 1. device on bus 002:06 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00364A09534141A'  
[ INFO] [1342603487.446153737]: Searching for device with index = 1  
[ INFO] [1342603487.520744291]: Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 2:6 with serial number 'A00364A09534141A'  
[ INFO] [1342603487.556152646]: rgb_frame_id = '/camera_rgb_optical_frame'   
[ INFO] [1342603487.556216539]: depth_frame_id= '/camera_depth_optical_frame'   
[ WARN] [1342603487.563057732]: Camera calibration file /home/ale/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00364A09534141A.yaml not found.  
[ WARN] [1342603487.563112210]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.  [ WARN] [1342603487.563158568]: Camera calibration file /home/ale/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00364A09534141A.yaml not found.  
[ WARN] [1342603487.563200355]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
```

Despite the errors it works. If I close the program and I restart openni_launch, I have:

[...]

```
[ERROR] [1342602671.015884628]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]                       
[ERROR] [1342602671.031949234]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]                       
[ INFO] [1342602678.285143378]: Number devices connected: 1           
[ INFO] [1342602678.285292312]: 1. device on bus 002:11 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00364A09534141A'     
[ INFO] [1342602678.286667631]: Searching for device with index = 1 
nodelet: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = xn::NodeInfo, boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference = xn::NodeInfo&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.              
[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 14263, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros /fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/ale/.ros/log/8292bcc6-d0b8-11e1-b766-c860005fdc27/camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/ale/.ros/log/8292bcc6-d0b8-11e1-b766-c860005fdc27/camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
```

The line "Initializing nodelet with 6 worker threads." is missing and the program crashes. In this case, if I use some programs from libfreenect such as "cppview" or "tiltdemo", kinect works. The only thing that I can do to reuse openni is to restart the pc!
Maybe it is a sort of ros initialization problem, I do not know. I noted also that the first time, openni_launch takes some seconds more to start up, it waits a little bit more on the line:

```
*Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.                 
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt*
```

Someone can help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39114/openni_launch-works-only-the-first-time/) by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 620 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-18**:
Sounds like the driver is getting hung and not shutting down. Can you tell if that node is still running after the first invocation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I found the problem. It seems that openni does not shut down properly. The XnSensorServer program still runs. If I kill the process then openni opens Kinect properly. I found other posts about that on pcl and openNI forum, so I think that it would be useful to add this tip to the wiki.
Thanks joq for the suggestion.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-07-23**:
Here's a ticket to keep track of this: https://kforge.ros.org/openni/trac/ticket/55

**Comment by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) on 2012-08-14**:
Hack attached to ticket

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-08-14**:
And here's another hack, that you can add to a kinect launchfile: https://bitbucket.org/jbohren/xnsensorserver-hack/src

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2012-10-11**:
There are quite a few other threads discussing this same issue in case that helps the ticket: [threadA](http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise-1204/) and [threadB](http://answers.ros.org/question/44367/openni_camera-crash-while-using-kinect/)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The only answer I found that worked for this was to run:

killall -s 9 XnSensorServer

before you rerun the openni_launch - this still does not solve all the other warnings but it does help not having to restart your entire system to get it running again..

---

Originally posted by [kleinash](https://answers.ros.org/users/2345/kleinash/) with karma: 56 on 2012-10-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1